# How to fix authentication through pgpool?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgpool

I have a cluster that consists of:

1. pgpool
2. master
3. slave

Using pgpool-II version 4.3.2 and
Postgres 14.4

Several users have been created, all are authenticated through pgpool.
There was a need to create new users.

In `pool_passwd` I create entries in this way:

```
pg_enc -m -f /etc/pgpool2/pgpool.conf -i users.txt
```

(in `users.txt` there are user logins and passwords)

When connecting with Dbeaver

> ERROR: backend authentication failed
> Details: backend response with
> kind 'E' when expecting 'R'

```
pg_md5 -m --config-file="/etc/pgpool2/pgpool.conf" -u "user" "pass"
```

> ERROR: failed to authenticate with backend using SCRAM
> Details: valid password not found

`pool_hba.conf`:

```
host    all         all         10.99.0.0/32          scram-sha-256
host    all         postgres    0.0.0.0/0             scram-sha-256

local   all         all                               md5
local   all         postgres                          scram-sha-256

host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5

local all all    trust
host  all all    10.99.0.0/32 trust
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

pgpool2.conf

```
enable_pool_hba = off
allow_clear_text_frontend_auth = on
pool_passwd = ''
```

this config works for me.

https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-ALLOW-CLEAR-TEXT-FRONTEND-AUTH